# Dockerfile install amqp failed

Tags: php, docker, dockerfile, amqp

I have some issues with my dockerfile... Here is the problem, I have a dockerfile based on this image -> FROM php:7.1.7-apache

I want to install amqp extension for php. I was using pecl but since recently when i build my container i get an error.

Here is the process i'm using in my dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.1.7-apache

MAINTAINER T3ddy <xx@xxx.com>

RUN apt-get update

## TOOLS
RUN apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    curl \
    git \
    htop \
    ncdu \
    netcat \
    net-tools \
    telnet \
    unzip \
    vim \
    wget

## PHP AMQP
RUN apt-get install -y librabbitmq-dev libssl-dev
RUN pecl install amqp
RUN docker-php-ext-enable amqp
```

And when i get to the point of pecl install amqp...

```
.......
/tmp/pear/temp/amqp/amqp.c: In function 'zm_startup_amqp':
/tmp/pear/temp/amqp/amqp.c:177:55: error: 'AMQP_SASL_METHOD_EXTERNAL' undeclared (first use in this function)
  REGISTER_LONG_CONSTANT("AMQP_SASL_METHOD_EXTERNAL",  AMQP_SASL_METHOD_EXTERNAL, CONST_CS | CONST_PERSISTENT);
                                                       ^
/usr/local/include/php/Zend/zend_constants.h:42:105: note: in definition of macro 'REGISTER_LONG_CONSTANT'
 #define REGISTER_LONG_CONSTANT(name, lval, flags)  zend_register_long_constant((name), sizeof(name)-1, (lval), (flags), module_number)
                                                                                                         ^
/tmp/pear/temp/amqp/amqp.c:177:55: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
  REGISTER_LONG_CONSTANT("AMQP_SASL_METHOD_EXTERNAL",  AMQP_SASL_METHOD_EXTERNAL, CONST_CS | CONST_PERSISTENT);
                                                       ^
/usr/local/include/php/Zend/zend_constants.h:42:105: note: in definition of macro 'REGISTER_LONG_CONSTANT'
 #define REGISTER_LONG_CONSTANT(name, lval, flags)  zend_register_long_constant((name), sizeof(name)-1, (lval), (flags), module_number)
                                                                                                         ^
Makefile:194: recipe for target 'amqp.lo' failed
make: *** [amqp.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
The command '/bin/sh -c pecl install amqp' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

And here is the error I got, I don't really understand why it failed, because since now it worked fine... Anyone got any idea. Or a solution on how to install amqp without using pecl maybe ?

Comment: What do you mean by "since now it worked fine"? Did you probably install other versions of all these packages in the past?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing AMQP through PECL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9520914/installing-amqp-through-pecl)

Comment: @NicoHaase I mean that it worked well without any more different configuration...

Comment: @LinPy Yes i tried but it didn't solved the problem...

Comment: Even if you didn't change the configuration, you have not specified the versions of each package you are installing. There's a new version of the amqp package on PECL since last week, maybe it contains a bug?

Answer (score 6):

I published a script that lets you install the amqp PHP extension (and many others) with just these lines:

```
ADD https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer/releases/latest/download/install-php-extensions /usr/local/bin/

RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/install-php-extensions && sync && \
    install-php-extensions amqp
```

the scripts takes care of the PHP version, and install all the required APT (for Debian) or APK (for Alpine) packages.

More details here: https://github.com/mlocati/docker-php-extension-installer

Comment: Thanks for this one. I did not know that i would need something like this one until i used it.

Answer (score 1):

There was a new version of AMQP released on 2019-01-02 ([1.9.4](https://pecl.php.net/package/amqp)) which is not compatible right now as it seems. You can explicitly install 1.9.3 with `pecl install amqp-1.9.3`